# Delete Cell content after Saveas

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am trying to delete the contents of few cell in the saved copies of my workbook that is under different file names. As code below, this is deleting the content from original workbook and retaining the content in the saved wb. It is doing the right opposite task that I wanted for!

Also, any suggestion on how to disable few modules and delete few pictures in the saved wb ?

Thanks in Advance for help !

```
 Sub SaveAsNewCopy()
 Dim Path As String
 Dim FileName1 As String

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 FileName1 = Range("D3")


  ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:="C:\Users\..\..\..\"    & FileName1 & "-" & "List" & ".xlsm"
  MsgBox "File Saved successfully!", , "Save"

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5:F5").ClearContents
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E9:F9").ClearContents

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `thisworkbook` with `workbook(filenameOfNewBook)`.

Comment: Filename of the workbook keeps changing! I have several files that needs to be saved .

Comment: Use the variable `& FileName1 & "-" & "List" & ".xlsm"` Edit: I like Oliver's architecture below better but he has it backwards.

Comment: Can you clarify how to use the variable  again as said in previous comment    & FileName1 & "-" & "List" & ".xlsm"

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a handle on the workbook you just saved, make the changes you want and then save it again. The easiest way to do this is to assign a variable to it. In your declarations do something like this:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
```

then before your save-as line assign the saved workbook to that variable like this:

Set wb = ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:="C:\Users......\"    & FileName1 & "-" & "List" & ".xlsm"

Then you can work with wb as required as save it with wb.Save True etc etc